# how to display selected value from dropdownlist to label using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 drop-down lists in my form. I want to display the selected value from each dropdown list to my label. The problem is that only one dropbox list will display, while the other two won't.

Here is my code:

```
<script>

window.onload = function()
{

document.getElementsByName('mydropdown')[0].onchange = function(e)
{
    document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = this.value;
};
}
</script>



this is my html

<td><select name="mydropdown" id="mydrop" onchange="">
<option value="none" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="17.50">6M</option>
<option value="25.00">12M</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><label id="mylabel"></label></td>

<td><select name="mydropdown" id="mydrop">
<option value="none" selected="selected">Length </option>
<option value="0.0455">DS516HO</option>
<option value="0.0559">DS520HO</option>
<option value="0.0780">DS516HWR</option>
<option value="0.0200">DS312WH</option>
<option value="0.0624">DS520WH</option>
<option value="0.0361">DS525FH</option>
<option value="0.1170">DS620HW</option>
<option value="0.1340">DS550HW</option>
<option value="0.1340">TD525HW</option>
<option value="0.1820">DS650HW</option>
<option value="0.2340">TD665HWR</option>
</select>
<td><label id="mylabel"></label></td>
```

Comment: Why dont you use `id` to select elements?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/x8Rdd/1/

That's because you are only setting the onchange event for the first element in your "mydropdown" group.

```
<script>

window.onload = function()
{
var dd = document.getElementsByName('mydropdown');    
for (var i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
    dd[i].onchange = function(e)
    {
        document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = this.value;
    };
}
}
</script>
```

Or something like that. If you're using jQuery then you can set the onchange property for all of them without the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're only binding the zeroth element (the one you selet) with `[0]`.  You need to bind to all of them, possibly like so:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByName('mydropdown'),
function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
        document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = this.value;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNLnx/

By the way you are reusing the same ID on multiple elements which is invalid.

Comment: this code work but only 1 label display if i choose any of dropdownlist..i want every label will display when user select from different dropdownlist..please help me..